# Firebase reset password open activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an android app and I am using Firebase.
I want to add a reset password option to my app, so I call the `sendPasswordResetEmail(email)` method. It works fine, but my problem is that the page that is opened by the reset password link lets the user reset his password by Firebase password's terms (For example, it lets the password to contain invalid characters).
I want to make the link open an activity in my own app so i will be able to control the reset password options.
Is it possible?

Comment: I don't want to change the method, I want to change the link that is sent in the email and make it open an activity in my app, instead of opening the Firebase automatic page

Comment: There is no way to control the password requirements of Firebase's email+password authentication. If you want to simply end up in your own app, consider sending your own email that then contains a [Dynamic Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) to the correct screen. But this won't change the underlying passwords requirements. You could also consider implementing your own authentication provider, which then can enforce the password requirements you want.

Comment: I understand, Thanks